# Syntax error in Prolog regarding <>

Tags: prolog

I have this Prolog code that must calculate the successor of a number, the number being represented in a list. The problem is that the code generates the "Syntax error: Operator expected" error on the -N<>0 part of the code. I searched everywhere for an equivalent of <>, but this is how I find it everywhere and how I learned it in class. What should I change to fix the error?

```
%successor of a number represented on a list
%[1 9 3 5 9 9]-->[1 9 3 6 0 0]
%domains
%   el=integer
%   list=el*
%predicates
%   add_fn(el,list,list)
%   inverted(list,list)
%   succesor(list,list)
%   suc(list,list,integer)
%clauses
   add_fn(E,[],[E]).
   add_fn(E,[H|T],[H|L]):-add_fn(E,T,L).

   inverted([],[]).
   inverted([H|T],L):-inverted(T,L1),add_fn(H,L1,L).

   succesor([],[]):-!.
   succesor(L,R):-inverted(L,LM),suc(LM,S,1),inverted(S,R).

   suc([],[],_):-!.
   suc([H|T],[H|L],N):-N=0,!,suc(T,L,0).
   suc([H|T],[M|L],N):-N<>0,!,S=H+N,M=S mod 10,N1=S div 10,suc(T,L,N1).
```

Comment: The syntax is Turbo/PDC-Prolog.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed all the differences, now the program runs as it should.